# How to formulate this question correctly: How these checklists have been developed?

Tags: grammar

How to formulate this question grammatically correct: ": How these checklists have been developed?"

Comment: What do you think is correct, and why?

Answer (score 1):

Probably "How have these checklists been developed?" if you're asking it like a question, but "How these checklists have been developed" if it is a part of a bigger sentence such as "Now we need to take a look at how these checklists have been developed".